# css как поднять блока выше родительского и ниже дочерного

Tags: css3, z-index

подскажите как заставить класса .content идти выше класса header-bar и header-ega и ниже класса header-content

```css
.header-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background: #098088;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
 .header-bar .header-content{
    background: #098088;
    clear:both;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    font-weight: 600;
    z-index:9;
    width: 100%;}

.header-bar .header-ega {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0; 
   width: 100%;
   height: 10px;
   background: #f8f8f8;
   border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;}

.content{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background: #f8f8f8;}
```

```html
<div class="header-bar">
   <div class="header-content"></div>
   <div class="header-ega"></div>
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: для начала `class` и `id` не путать

Comment: @Zhihar не нужно исправлять ошибки в коде без ведома автора, они могут влиять на суть вопроса

Comment: @andreymal, данные ошибки на суть вопроса не влияли, поэтому и исправил

Answer (score 0):

в css очень странная система порядков (поищите в сети)

но самое главное что вам надо знать - `z-index` работает только внутри блока, т.е. никогда дочерний элемент не будет выше или ниже соседского

```
<div class = 'parent'>
    <div class = 'child'>...</div>
</div>
<div class = 'neighbor'>
...
</div>
```

т.е. блок `child` может перемещаться вверх/вниз только внутри `parent` относительно детей `parent`, т.е. своих соседей

и никак `child` отдельно от `parent` не сможет встать выше/ниже соседа `parent` (т.е. блока `neighbor`)

к сожалению

т.е. вы можете спозиционировать `parent` относительно `neighbor` и изменить ему порядок отрисовки, но все дочерние элементы `parent` будут или выше (если `parent` выше) или ниже (если `parent` ниже) `neighbor`

единственный вариант - вытаскивать детей из родителя и делать их родительскими соседями, т.е. равноправными участниками позиционирования

Comment: а с помощью js можно как нибудь манипулировать что бы получить такой результат ?

Comment: через `z-index` - нет, только если вы будете создавать новые блоки (именно соседей), но все будет упираться в те же самые правила

Comment: @Zhihar странно, вот child выше чем neighbor https://jsfiddle.net/Lg4fuzva/

Comment: @andreymal, да, действительно, что-то я не то понаписал значит - https://webformyself.com/prichiny-po-kotorym-z-index-css-ne-rabotaet/ - вот 4 пункт